# Is there a way to install ora2pg tool on a Linux machine without having Perl installed first?

Tags: linux, postgresql, oraclelinux, ora2pg

Usually the installation of "ora2pg" database migration tool on a Linux machine requires Perl, so I was wondering if there is an alternative way of installing the tool.

Comment: I guess the tool is written in Perl, and as such requires Perl to run. But this isn't a programming question, and thus off-topic on Stack Overflow.

Comment: sorry, i didn't mean to bother

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ora2pg is written in Perl, so you cannot run it without installing Perl.